# IndexOutOfBoundsException when deleting an item from RecyclerView

Tags: android

```
 holder.scrollView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                private float y;
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    switch (event.getAction()) {
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN :
                            if (event.getPointerCount() >= 2) {
                                y = event.getY();
                            }
                            return true;
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE :
                            if (event.getPointerCount() >= 2) {
                                float deltaY = event.getY();
                                if ((deltaY - y) >= 50) {
                                    removeItem(i);
                                    return true;
                                } else {
                                    return false;
                                }
                            } else {
                                return false;
                            }
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });
```

Here's my remove item method :

```
  public void removeItem(int position) {
            Entry entry = entries.get(position); //It's pointing at this line INDEXOUTOFBOUNDSEXCEPTION

            Iterator iterator = entries.iterator();
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                Entry e = (Entry) iterator.next();
                if (e.key.equals(entry.key)) {
                    iterator.remove();
                }
            }
            notifyDataSetChanged();

        }
```

I'm pretty sure it has something to do with how `RecyclerView`s behave. I've been trying to search for 5 hours now but to no avail. Can someone please help me with this.

Comment: What position you pass when call `removeItem(i);`? What is the value of `i`?

Comment: What is "i"? Is it the position in `onBindViewHolder`?

Comment: i is the position in bindviewholder

Comment: post your stacktrace

Comment: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0

Comment: Do you populate your RecyclerView with `entries`?

Answer (score 0):

You must check to get item count, it's showing no item to remove

```
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return list.size();
}
```